# How to solve boost thread_resource_error

Tags: bash, centos

I have an application and it's just killing me. I have a server Centos 7 with 2gb ram and I can't start an application on the server but I can start it on another server with just 512mb ram. What can I do about this ?

```
boost::thread_resource_error

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::thread_resource_error'
  what():  boost::thread_resource_error
Aborted
```

I have tried `echo 1000000 > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` but it's giving me permission denied. `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max: Permission denied`

Comment: no idea the application is compiled and I don't have the source code.

Comment: Then, technically, it's not related to programming at all. Try http://superuser.com.

Comment: And yes, you should change system settings being root, since it's a privileged operation.

Comment: I am root but still not able to change that while on the other server with 512 mb ram I was able to change...